# Mono 100% CPU spin in mono_conc_hashtable_lookup

Tags: mono

I have an app that is a offline batch task processor. Basically a task runner that accepts input on stdin, executes the given command task, stores output via NHibernate against a MySQL database. It's not complex and runs single threaded (think Apache Prefork model).

In deploying to a more modern version of mono,  I've been having the processes get hung using 100% of a cpu core. The app is normally deployed on Linux, but I've been able reproduce it under the Visual Studio Community for Mac debugger on Mono 5.8.1 and 5.12.0.233. Under Visual Studio Community, when I break the application I don't get any information about what statement is executing.

Dropping down to gdb on Linux I do get the following backtraces:

**backtrace:**

```
    #0  0x00000000006fdff0 in mono_conc_hashtable_lookup (hash_table=0xf174e0, key=key@entry=0x963d4f0) at mono-conc-hashtable.c:175
    #1  0x000000000042fd29 in mono_jit_runtime_invoke (method="System.Object:lambda_method ()", obj=0x0, params=0x7fffb1067c10, exc=0x0, 
        error=0x7fffb1067d00) at mini-runtime.c:2668
    #2  0x0000000000605a8f in do_runtime_invoke (method="System.Object:lambda_method ()", obj=, params=, 
        exc=, error=0x7fffb1067d00) at object.c:2922
    #3  0x0000000000611911 in mono_runtime_try_invoke_array (method=method@entry="System.Object:lambda_method ()", obj=obj@entry=0x0, 
        params=params@entry=0x7fdb5d61fe68, exc=exc@entry=0x0, error=error@entry=0x7fffb1067d00) at object.c:5261
    #4  0x0000000000611bd0 in mono_runtime_invoke_array_checked (method=method@entry="System.Object:lambda_method ()", obj=obj@entry=0x0, 
        params=params@entry=0x7fdb5d61fe68, error=error@entry=0x7fffb1067d00) at object.c:5139
    #5  0x00000000005c17fb in ves_icall_InternalInvoke (method=0x7fdb5d61fe40, this_arg=0x0, params=0x7fdb5d61fe68, exc=0x7fffb1067e70) at icall.c:3392
    #6  0x0000000040c4081a in ?? ()
    #7  0x00007fdb5d5ab2a0 in ?? ()
    #8  0x00007fdb5d61e688 in ?? ()
    #9  0x00007fdb5d61e828 in ?? ()
    #10 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

**mono_backtrace**

```
    #0  0x00000000006fdff0 in mono_conc_hashtable_lookup (hash_table=0xf174e0, key=key@entry=0x963d4f0) at mono-conc-hashtable.c:175
    175             if (key == kvs [i].key) {
    [New Thread 0x7fdaf9b1d700 (LWP 11880)]
    #1  0x000000000042fd29 in mono_jit_runtime_invoke (method="System.Object:lambda_method ()", obj=0x0, params=0x7fffb1067c10, exc=0x0, 
        error=0x7fffb1067d00) at mini-runtime.c:2668
    2668        info = (RuntimeInvokeInfo *)mono_conc_hashtable_lookup (domain_info->runtime_invoke_hash, method);
    [New Thread 0x7fdb50baa700 (LWP 11881)]
    #2  0x0000000000605a8f in do_runtime_invoke (method="System.Object:lambda_method ()", obj=, params=, 
        exc=, error=0x7fffb1067d00) at object.c:2922
    2922        result = callbacks.runtime_invoke (method, obj, params, exc, error);
    #3  0x0000000000611911 in mono_runtime_try_invoke_array (method=method@entry="System.Object:lambda_method ()", obj=obj@entry=0x0, 
        params=params@entry=0x7fdb5d61fe68, exc=exc@entry=0x0, error=error@entry=0x7fffb1067d00) at object.c:5261
    5261                res = mono_runtime_invoke_checked (method, obj, pa, error);
    #4  0x0000000000611bd0 in mono_runtime_invoke_array_checked (method=method@entry="System.Object:lambda_method ()", obj=obj@entry=0x0, 
        params=params@entry=0x7fdb5d61fe68, error=error@entry=0x7fffb1067d00) at object.c:5139
    5139        return mono_runtime_try_invoke_array (method, obj, params, NULL, error);
    [New Thread 0x7fdaf8d27700 (LWP 11882)]
    #5  0x00000000005c17fb in ves_icall_InternalInvoke (method=0x7fdb5d61fe40, this_arg=0x0, params=0x7fdb5d61fe68, exc=0x7fffb1067e70) at icall.c:3392
    3392        MonoObject *result = mono_runtime_invoke_array_checked (m, obj, params, error);
    #6 0x40c4081a in  (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&) {0x12a4498} + 0x6a (0x40c407b0 0x40c4088c) [0xf125d0 - MOAB.Task.TaskRunner.exe]
    [New Thread 0x7fdb509a9700 (LWP 11884)]
    #7  0x00007fdb5d5ab2a0 in ?? ()
    #8  0x00007fdb5d61e688 in ?? ()
    #9  0x00007fdb5d61e828 in ?? ()
    #10 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

When this occurs, a most threads are sleeping:

```
      Id   Target Id         Frame 
      15   Thread 0x7fdb5d3ff700 (LWP 11515) "SGen worker" pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 ()
        at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/pthread_cond_wait.S:185
      14   Thread 0x7fdb5aee5700 (LWP 11516) "Finalizer" 0x00007fdb6458da0b in futex_abstimed_wait (cancel=true, private=, abstime=0x0, 
        expected=0, futex=0xa45c00 ) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/sem_waitcommon.c:43
      13   Thread 0x7fdb515df700 (LWP 11519) "Timer-Scheduler" pthread_cond_timedwait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 ()
        at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/pthread_cond_timedwait.S:238
      12   Thread 0x7fdb50dab700 (LWP 11520) "Thread Pool I/O" 0x00007fdb64094a3d in poll () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:81
      11   Thread 0x7fdaf991c700 (LWP 11572) "Datastore Capac" pthread_cond_timedwait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 ()
        at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/pthread_cond_timedwait.S:238
      10   Thread 0x7fdaebfff700 (LWP 11822) "Thread Pool Wor" 0x00007fdb6458dc21 in futex_abstimed_wait (cancel=true, private=0, abstime=0x7fdaebffeda0, 
        expected=0, futex=0xa465c8 ) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/sem_waitcommon.c:87
      9    Thread 0x7fdaeaed3700 (LWP 11879) "Thread Pool Wor" 0x00007fdb6458dc21 in futex_abstimed_wait (cancel=true, private=0, abstime=0x7fdaeaed2da0, 
        expected=0, futex=0xa465c8 ) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/sem_waitcommon.c:87
      8    Thread 0x7fdb509a9700 (LWP 11884) "Thread Pool Wor" 0x00007fdb6458dc21 in futex_abstimed_wait (cancel=true, private=0, abstime=0x7fdb509a8da0, 
        expected=0, futex=0xa465c8 ) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/sem_waitcommon.c:87
      7    Thread 0x7fdaf9d1e700 (LWP 11944) "Thread Pool Wor" 0x00007fdb6458dc21 in futex_abstimed_wait (cancel=true, private=0, abstime=0x7fdaf9d1dda0, 
        expected=0, futex=0xa465c8 ) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/sem_waitcommon.c:87
      6    Thread 0x7fdaeacd2700 (LWP 11993) "Thread Pool Wor" 0x00007fdb6458dc21 in futex_abstimed_wait (cancel=true, private=0, abstime=0x7fdaeacd1da0, 
        expected=0, futex=0xa465c8 ) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/sem_waitcommon.c:87
      5    Thread 0x7fdaf9b1d700 (LWP 12002) "Thread Pool Wor" 0x00007fdb6458dc21 in futex_abstimed_wait (cancel=true, private=0, abstime=0x7fdaf9b1cda0, 
        expected=0, futex=0xa465c8 ) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/sem_waitcommon.c:87
      4    Thread 0x7fdaf8d27700 (LWP 12201) "Thread Pool Wor" 0x00007fdb6458dc21 in futex_abstimed_wait (cancel=true, private=0, abstime=0x7fdaf8d26da0, 
        expected=0, futex=0xa465c8 ) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/sem_waitcommon.c:87
      3    Thread 0x7fdb507a8700 (LWP 12631) "Thread Pool Wor" 0x00007fdb6458dc21 in futex_abstimed_wait (cancel=true, private=0, abstime=0x7fdb507a7da0, 
        expected=0, futex=0xa465c8 ) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/sem_waitcommon.c:87
      2    Thread 0x7fdae8899700 (LWP 12632) "Thread Pool Wor" 0x00007fdb6458dc21 in futex_abstimed_wait (cancel=true, private=0, abstime=0x7fdae8898da0, 
        expected=0, futex=0xa465c8 ) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/sem_waitcommon.c:87
    * 1    Thread 0x7fdb650b3780 (LWP 11511) "TaskRunner" 0x00000000006fdff0 in mono_conc_hashtable_lookup (hash_table=0xf174e0, key=key@entry=0x963d4f0)
        at mono-conc-hashtable.c:175
```

The code for mono_conc_hashtable_lookup:

```
    158 mono_conc_hashtable_lookup (MonoConcurrentHashTable *hash_table, gpointer key)
    159 {
    160         MonoThreadHazardPointers* hp;
    161         conc_table *table;
    162         int hash, i, table_mask;
    163         key_value_pair *kvs;
    164         hash = mix_hash (hash_table->hash_func (key));
    165         hp = mono_hazard_pointer_get ();
    166 
    167 retry:
    168         table = (conc_table *)mono_get_hazardous_pointer ((gpointer volatile*)&hash_table->table, hp, 0);
    169         table_mask = table->table_size - 1;
    170         kvs = table->kvs;
    171         i = hash & table_mask;
    172 
    173         if (G_LIKELY (!hash_table->equal_func)) {
    174                 while (kvs [i].key) {
    175                         if (key == kvs [i].key) {
    176                                 gpointer value;
    177                                 /* The read of keys must happen before the read of values */
    178                                 mono_memory_barrier ();
    179                                 value = kvs [i].value;
    180                                 /* FIXME check for NULL if we add suppport for removal */
    181                                 mono_hazard_pointer_clear (hp, 0);
    182                                 return value;
    183                         }
    184                         i = (i + 1) & table_mask;
    185                 }
    186         } else {
    187                 GEqualFunc equal = hash_table->equal_func;
    188 
    189                 while (kvs [i].key) {
    190                         if (kvs [i].key != TOMBSTONE && equal (key, kvs [i].key)) {
    191                                 gpointer value;
    192                                 /* The read of keys must happen before the read of values */
    193                                 mono_memory_barrier ();
    194                                 value = kvs [i].value;
    195 
    196                                 /* We just read a value been deleted, try again. */
    197                                 if (G_UNLIKELY (!value))
    198                                         goto retry;
    199 
    200                                 mono_hazard_pointer_clear (hp, 0);
    201                                 return value;
    202                         }
    203                         i = (i + 1) & table_mask;
    204                 }
    205         }
    206 
    207         /* The table might have expanded and the value is now on the newer table */
    208         mono_memory_barrier ();
    209         if (hash_table->table != table)
    210                 goto retry;
    211 
    212         mono_hazard_pointer_clear (hp, 0);
    213         return NULL;
    214 }
```

Setting breakpoints at the returns, 182,201,213:

```
    (gdb) break 182 thread 1
    Breakpoint 4 at 0x6fdff5: file mono-conc-hashtable.c, line 182.
    (gdb) break 201 thread 1
    Breakpoint 5 at 0x6fe0e0: file mono-conc-hashtable.c, line 201.
    (gdb) break 213 thread 1
    Breakpoint 6 at 0x6fe024: file mono-conc-hashtable.c, line 213.
```

Those breakpoints never get hit infinite loop? Let's try the gotos:

```
    (gdb) break 198 thread 1
    Breakpoint 5 at 0x6fe0d5: file mono-conc-hashtable.c, line 198.
    (gdb) break 210 thread 1
    Breakpoint 6 at 0x6fe019: file mono-conc-hashtable.c, line 210.
```

These don't appear to get hit as well.

I focused on i = (i + 1) & table_mask; at line 184:

```
    Breakpoint 12, mono_conc_hashtable_lookup (hash_table=0xf174e0, key=key@entry=0x963d4f0) at mono-conc-hashtable.c:184
    184             i = (i + 1) & table_mask;
    (gdb) p i
    $15 = 4095
    (gdb) p table_mask
    $16 = 4095
    (gdb) s
    174         while (kvs [i].key) {
    (gdb) p i
    $17 = 0
```

It appears it's scanning the kvs keys using i as an index, but when i reaches the table_mask value, it gets reset to 0 due to the mask, and loops onward.

At this point, I'm stuck and am asking for how to debug this further? I'm at my limit on knowledge of mono internals. Is this really entering an endless loop? If so, what is the scenario where entering mono_conc_hashtable_lookup will trigger it?

**Other Notes:**

The issue occurs at random times and is not consistent in its pattern.

Comment: I have the same exact problem! And I thought I was the only one... I really don't know what to do with this, as it's disrupting my application hardly. Have you found any solution?

Comment: Can you replicate the problem with a single class application? If so, you could share it, and we could try our hands at debugging it.

Comment: I haven't looked at this in awhile. I ended up downgrading to mono 4.6.2, which doesn't exhibit the issue for my workload. I was hoping to have a #mono dev decribe what mono_conc_hashtable_lookup() is primarily used for so I could try and narrow it down. From what I remember, mono_conc_hashtable_lookup() hasn't changed between 4.6.2 and more recent versions, indicating the actual culprit is elsewhere.

Comment: I actually ended up understanding the root of my problem with similar symptoms. Ended up being a deadlock in part of my code. Fixing the deadlock seems to have mitigated the problem.